# Magento 2 CE on Windows 10 XAMPP

Tags: magento2, installation, localhost, windows, xampp

Magento 2.n.n

Started with **composer** to get metapackage. Following the command-line of

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition <installation directory name>
```

How do you **set pre-installation file system ownership and permissions** on Windows?

1. Created a blank database. **Magento_2**
2. Setup v-host configuration for  **magento-2.local**
3. Used Google Chrome browser to install Magento 2 in the browser.
4. All steps completed successfully.

**Everything okay at this point**

Clicked on the 2 links on the success page.

http://magento-2.local

[http://magento-2.local/admin](http://%20http://magento-2.local/admin)

All **Magento base** JS, CSS and Magento images for dashboard not found.

Does anyone know what is the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You must write static view files to the Magento file system manually using the command:

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`